# High-stakes tests: How messy can an optical scan sheet be and still be readable?

Tags: teaching, exams, reference-request, disability

A student has traditionally been given a 504 accommodation to be permitted to mark answers to multiple choice questions directly in the test booklet, for a proctor to transfer the answers to the bubble sheet (optical scan sheet).  Now he's in a situation where this accommodation has been rejected.

If you're curious, his difficulty with bubble sheets has to do with ADHD, OCD, anxiety and sensory integration disorder.  He sometimes presses too hard, sometimes too light.  It is inherently hard for him to bubble neatly, but he also obsesses about it, and this ends up wearing him out mentally, leaving him less able to concentrate on the content of the test questions.

Well, okay, he lost the battle (for the accommodation) and will regroup for the war (e.g. updated neuropsych testing has already been scheduled), but in the meantime, there is a high-stakes test on Tuesday and I have to figure out just how messy the bubbles can be, and still be readable.  This will help lower the anxiety for the student.  (Today is Saturday.)

What I have found so far: "Most systems accommodate for human error in filling in ovals imprecisely, as long as they do not stray into the other ovals and the oval is almost completely filled."  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_answer_sheet))

I need images showing the threshold.  A messy but acceptable bubble and a messy bubble that the scanner coughed on.

Here is a screenshot of what the bubbles look like for this particular high-stakes test:

[image]

Comment: I feel like the answer to this depends on the machine, not sure how we can answer how accurate the machine can be.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine? You could try a number of different bubbling "techniques", say ten each way, to see what the accuracy is. At the end of the day, I would *hope* that if the Scantron is returned to the student graded, and they can demonstrate that it misgraded a number of questions, that a standard academic grievance should be sufficient to restore the proper grade. (While a professor might be a dick about such things, from what I've heard talking to the disability resource center at my university, department heads and up to be more reasonable)

Comment: I believe this will be more answerable and in scope if you change this from "How does this machine work?" to "How do I deal with this problem, given that we have to use the machine?"

Comment: @guifa - Access to the machine?  Look, I had evaluations.  I had the evaluators in the meeting.  But I lost.  These people are beyond unreasonable.  There are good guys and bad guys in this world. // No, the Scantron will not be returned to the student graded. // We are waay beyond standard academic grievances.

Comment: @jakebeal - I have a strategy to deal with the problem, in general terms, I just need some technical information so when the student practices bubbling, I can compare the results against the images and say, this one is fine, this one will cause a hiccup. // If there's a different SE site that would get me a quicker answer, I'm all ears.  We have to figure this out by tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: @aparente001 Our Scantron machines just sit out in the open, it's not like students get any advantage by seeing them, even if someone from the disability office were blocked, I figure a sympathetic professor who did have access could run some test tests through. Although not the point of this question, is it the disability office that's blocking the accomodation or the professor that refuses to allow the accomodation deemed necessary by the disability office?

Comment: @guifa - It's complicated. // The machines aren't out in the open.  // Do you feel like doing a couple of tests with your machine?  I'll understand if you don't have time or interest.

Comment: @aparente I probably could either late Sunday or sometime Monday. I'm out of town this weekend and not sure if I'll be in the office Sunday, but I'm happy to try something out. I hate when professors won't make incredibly reasonable accomodations.

Comment: @guifa - Very nice of you....  Maybe I'll have found some additional information between now and then.  // Strangely, this exam requires that the bubbles be filled in with *pen* -- black or blue.

Comment: Scantrons put to the test: http://www.thechurchillobserver.com/features/2012/05/01/scantrons-put-to-the-test/

Comment: Could you accommodate the student personally by giving the  bubbles more black before the machine sees the form?

Comment: @AaronBrick - Imagine a 3yo trying not to go outside the lines.  Now imagine you are a teenager with a similar lack of control over what your number 2 pencil does; now imagine you have an anxiety disorder, and your exam performance is affected by your OCD about the mess you're making of the bubble sheet.  It distracts you from doing your best with the exam.